# Odds ratio with three level dependent variable

Tags: r, glm

I'm trying to calculate odds ratios for a 3-level dependent variable.

I have figured out how to do odds ratios with a binary depression score (lowest 25% of test scores = 1, all others = 0) by doing this:

```
ODDSR <-glm(DEPRESSION~AGE+MALE+LITERACY+COLLEGE+MARRIED, data = df, family = "binomial")

summary(ODDSR)

exp(cbind(OR = coef(ODDSR), confint(ODDSR)))
```

But when I try to make the dependent variable into 3 levels:
- lowest 25% depression scores = 0
- middle 50% depression scores = 1
- top 25% depression scores = 2

glm reports an error and won't run.

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

It might even be worth looking at the dependent variable in 4 levels (each quartile numbered 0,1,2,3), but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: We are setting `family = "binomial"` i.e.: binary and supplying 3 variables?

Comment: As suggested by zx8754, with > 2 levels the problem is now multinomial, not binomial. You could try _e.g._ `multinom` in the `nnet` package: http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/

Comment: @zx8754, Yes, you are right I need to take out the family as "binomial" but I don't know what to replace it with to make the third line of code give me 2 sets of odds ratios, one for the middle 50% of scores compared to the lowest 25% of scores and one for the top 25% of scores compared to the lowest 25%.

Comment: Proportional odds logistic regression. Several packages offer it, including the rms package.

Comment: Should also look at `MASS:polr` for "Ordered Logistic or Probit Regression". It has the advantage over using `rms::lrm` in that it doesn't need the accessory data preparation that rms-functions require. My preference has been to accept that added effort as a small price to pay for added functionality in the rms "environment".

Answer (score 0):

install package nnet,

```
library(nnet)
ODDSR <-multinom(DEPRESSION~AGE+MALE+LITERACY+COLLEGE+MARRIED, data = df)
exp(confint(ODDSR)) 
exp(coef(ODDSR))
```

made it work